# Connect a desktop computer with HDMI, Display port, VGI, and DVI to a Dell docking station with USB-C

Tags: usb, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I recently bought a Dell docking station (WD19S 130W) and connected my Dell laptop to two monitors. The docking station-laptop connection is through USB-C. Everything works as expected for this setup.

Now, I want to switch between the laptop and my desktop computer, which only has HDMI, DVI, and DP ports. My question is: how can I connect the USB-C output from the docking station to the desktop computer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Docking stations are for convenience to not have to plug in every cable in the laptop every time. Desktops tend to be plugged in for way longer so they dont need a docking station... Just connect the monitors to your computer directly and switch between the input-sources.

Comment: "How can I connect the USB-C output from the docking station to the desktop computer?" - You don't.  Your desktop doesn't have the proper connections.  The solution to your problem is a KVM.  However, most KVM(s) are limited to HDMI and DisplayPort (or VGA/DVI which wouldn't be helpful in your setup)

Comment: Thank you both. I have tried the KVM solution before, but it did not work well. The idea of switching between the input sources seems to be the best solution in my case!